# Select inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select input fields with names like `name="myinput[something][etc]"` ?

`$('input[name=myinput[something][etc]')` doesnt seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[name="myinput[something][etc]"]');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just give them `id` attributes. It will save you a lot of grief.

Or you could try `$('input[name="myinput[something][etc]"]')`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name="myinput[something][etc]"]')
```

if want to select by id, then it must be

```
$('input[id=""]')
```

hope this....